# Narrow down refilling options to single sub-heading

Tags: org-mode

I have a single file `tasks.org` that contains all the tasks for agenda and I have separate projects files with a tasks related to specific project. I try to setup a configuration that will let me refile tasks from project files under the heading `* Projects` in `tasks.org` file and from the `tasks.org` file back to specific project file under heading `** Tasks`.

I try to use `:regexp` to narrow down refilling options to specific heading, but it doesn't work at all, it works only when I use `:level` parameter - maybe there is a bug in "regexp" parameter implementation or I use it wrong way.

Global `org-refile-targets`:

```
(setq org-refile-targets `(
                            (,my/project-1 :level . 1)
                            (,my/project-2 :regexp . "Projects$")))
```

The example project file:

```
# -*- mode: org -*-
# Local Variables:
# eval: (setq-local org-refile-targets `((,my/org-tasks-file-path :regexp . "Projects$")))
# End:

* Project 1
** Tasks
*** TODO bar
** Resources
```

Example `tasks.org` file:

```
# -*- mode: org -*-

* Tasks
** TODO foo
* Projects
```

---

EDIT:
I managed to succesfully refile task from tasks.org to project file. The problem was that there were different heading depths. The tasks.org have 2 levels and project file had 3. I changed project file to match number of heading levels with tasks file and now it works.

The project.org file look like this now:

```
# -*- mode: org -*-

* Project 1
** Tasks
*** TODO bar
** Resources
```

The only problem that left is to narrow down local refiling options for project file to just tasks.org `* Projects`. Local Variables with eval doesn't work. When I eval `(setq-local org-refile-targets` ((,my/org-tasks-file-path :regexp . "Projects$")))` by hand it works though.

Any idea how can I set `org-refile-targets` on file level?

Comment: The `Local Variables:` section has to be at  [the end of the file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables). That may have been the reason that `eval:` did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

I created `.dir-locals.el` file to set local `org-refile-targets` for all the files in the `projects` folder.

`.dir-locals.el`:

```
((nil . (
          (eval . (progn (jarfar/org-projects-set-refile-targets-local)))
          )))
```

I defined `jarfar/org-projects-set-refile-targets-local` to set local variable, because `.dir-locals.el` syntax is quite limited, but we can call functions inside of it so we are all good. The function looks like this:

```
(defun jarfar/org-projects-set-refile-targets-local ()
  "Set local 'org-refile-targets for project org files."
  (setq-local org-refile-targets `((,jarfar/org-tasks-file-path :regexp . "Projects$"))))
```

Read first post EDIT together with this one for complete solution.

---

EDIT: I decided to move local folder config from `.dir-locals.el` to general config:

```
(setq jarfar/org-projects-folder "~/Documents/emacs/projects)
(dir-locals-set-class-variables 'jarfar/projects-directory
  '((nil . (
     (eval . (progn (jarfar/org-projects-set-refile-targets-local)))
     ))))
(dir-locals-set-directory-class jarfar/org-projects-folder 'jarfar/projects-directory)
```